# How can I convert AFDataResponse<Data> into Data in order to render an Image using bytes?

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire, urlsession

I've created a Service file in order to handle all of my networking within the Weather Application that I am fine tuning. Within this service file, I use protocols, in order to return the retrieved data from GET requests to the appropriate View Controller.

During my code refactoring, and for the sake of learning, rather than using URLSessions, I decided I wanted to learn how to use Alamofire.

One of my GET requests retrieves an image of either a (sun, cloud, rain cloud, etc.), depending on the weather of a certain city (this is an example of the URL I am submitting my GET request to: http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03n@2x.png.

Before I imported Alomofire, I would GET the bytes of this image, and render the bytes within UIImage like so:

```
self.weatherIcon.image = UIImage(data: result)
```

This worked just fine. But now, when using Alamofire for my request, the challenge I am having is that I'm unable to convert AFDataResponse to type Data, in order to then be rendered to UIImage.

Below you may see my GET Request.

```
AF.request(myUrl).responseData{response in
   debugPrint(reponse)
   self.delegate3?.iconServiceDelegateDidFinishWithData(result: response)
}
```

The response is of type **AFDataResponse**.

Therefore, when trying to write:

```
self.weatherIcon.image = UIImage(data: result)
```

I get an error saying,

> Cannot convert value of type 'AFDataResponse (aka 'DataResponse<Data, AFError') to expected argument type 'Data'.

Any help would be much appreciated from the community.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

Create a variable of type Data and assign response.data to this variable.

```
AF.request(myUrl).responseData{ response in
   debugPrint(response)
   var imgData : Data                    //create variable of type data
   imgData = Data(response.data!)       // access the data through response.data
   self.delegate3?.iconServiceDelegateDidFinishWithData(result: imgData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can access the `data` directly, as you originally suggested (though I would treat it as an `Optional` rather than force unwrapping, as it'll crash otherwise).

```swift
.responseData { response in
    let image = response.data.map(UIImage.init(data:)) // Creates UIImage?
}
```

You can transform the `Result` value to maintain any `Error` you receive.

```swift
.responseData { response in
    let image = response.result.map(UIImage.init(data:)) // Creates Result<UIImage, AFError>
}
```

Or you can map the entire `DataResponse`.

```swift
.responseData { response in
    let imageResponse = response.map(UIImage.init(data:)) // Creates DataResponse<UIImage, AFError>
}
```